# Calculation of spread arbitrage profit

Tags: arbitrage

I would like to know if my spread (arbitrage) calculation is correct or wrong. as an example i have bitcoins which i would like to use for the ethereum i am going to buy at market A and sell at market B.

Calculation:

1(**BUY AMOUNT BTC** * **BID PRICE** = **BUY PRICE**)

2(**BUY AMOUNT BTC** - **WITHDRAW FEE** = **SELL AMOUNT BTC**)

3(**SELL AMOUNT BTC** * **BID PRICE** = **SELL PRICE**)

4((**BUY PRICE** - **BUY PRICE** * **TRADE FEE**) + **WITHDRAW FEE**) = **TOTAL BUY PRICE**

5((**SELL PRICE** + **SELL PRICE** * **TRADE FEE**) - **WITHDRAW FEE**) = **TOTAL SELL PRICE**

6(**TOTAL SELL PRICE** - **TOTAL BUY PRICE** = **TOTAL PROFIT**)

What i don't understand from this calculation is why is it BUY PRICE **- BUY PRICE ??** and SELL PRICE **+ SELL PRICE ??**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because arbitrage profit is a financial question

Comment: A buy is a debit (- sign)  and a sell is a credit (+ sign).  Also, you buy at the ask price and sell at the bid price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deplore the notation used, and haven't checked the overall validity.

But I suggest you see 'BUY PRICE - BUY PRICE*TRADE FEE' as BUYPRICE * (1-TRADEFEE). Same for the sell side.

Maybe it makes more sense to you now?

Comment: What if we use numbers for example: 0.5 btc and a tradefee of .25% does the following calculation makes sense: 0.5 *( 1 - 0.0025) = TOTAL BUY PRICE

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get this formula from? Look incorrect to me.

Here is what I would calculate like:

**Assume:** Trade fee is 1% so, 0.01, withdrawal fee is flatrate at 0.001 btc, or whatever it is at the moment converted to USD.

```
BUY PRICE = AMOUNT * ASK + AMOUNT * ASK * TRADE FEE + WITHDRAWAL FEE
SELL PRICE = AMOUNT * BID - AMOUNT * BID * TRADE FEE

PROFIT = SELL PRICE - BUY PRICE
```